# ggstattsplot : Why ggwithinstats not working with categorical data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to run the ggwithinstats function from ggstatplot but I get the following error.

This is I'm running

```
ggwithinstats( # independent samples
  data = dat,
  x = FAB,
  y = BM_percentage,
  plot.type = "box", # for boxplot
  type = "nonparametric", # for wilcoxon
  centrality.plotting = FALSE # remove median
)

########################
ggwithinstats(
   df2,
  x = FAB,
  y = BM_percentage
)
```

I get the error for the first code

> Error in validObject(.Object) :    invalid class “dsparseModelMatrix”
> object: superclass "Mnumeric" not defined in the environment of the
> object's class Error in validObject(.Object) :    invalid class
> “dsparseModelMatrix” object: superclass "Mnumeric" not defined in the
> environment of the object's class Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not
> all arguments have the same length

And for the second code I get this

> Error in p.adjust(pp[lower.tri(pp, TRUE)], p.adjust.method) :
> (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

My data which I'm trying to run

```
 b <- dput(dat)
structure(list(FAB = structure(c(5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("M0", 
"M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5"), class = "factor"), WBC = c(76.7, 
5, 5, 27.7, 10.7, 2.1, 78.5, 8.2, 47.2, 72.1, 67.5, 2.9, 22.2, 
1, 15.2, 7.3, 12.6, 27.6, 46.4, 27.1, 34.2, 33.5, 2.5, 2.3, 8.3, 
61.6, 47.6, 5.6, 137.2, 3.4, 48, 13.6, 0.9, 5.5, 1.5, 4.1, 90.4, 
34.8, 3.1, 2.3, 37, 34, 2.7, 17, 29.4, 50.3, 0.5, 4, 12.4, 12, 
111, 77.3, 2.9, 37.9, 8.3, 57.1, 11.5, 37.5, 6.1, 90.6, 80.5, 
10.1, 1.5, 30.8, 2.3, 0.4, 86.4, 34.6, 15.1, 35.9, 17.9, 0.7, 
33.2, 45.6, 98.8, 26.1, 134.4, 98.2, 8.4, 2.1, 67.9, 51.8, 5.1, 
2.6, 43.1, 6.7, 30.5, 171.9, 29.7, 75.2, 45, 11.5, 22.9, 131.5, 
63.7, 1.6, 5.4, 116.2, 14.9, 202.7, 18.7, 52.9, 99.2, 13.5, 14.5, 
2.7, 1.2, 8.2, 30.9, 103.6, 93, 5.1, 3.4, 0.9, 4.9, 42.1, 6.4, 
1.5, 59.3, 88.1, 25.9, 31.5, 223.8, 29, 9.9, 1.7, 0.6, 14.3, 
61.6, 2.2, 1.2, 16, 11, 92, 29.4, 32.4, 42.8, 2.9, 6.7, 1.2, 
13.1, 1, 3.6, 4.3, 39.8, 19.6, 101.3), TMB = c(0, 0.733333333333, 
0.3, 0.266666666667, 0.466666666667, 0.333333333333, 0.233333333333, 
0.2, 0.5, 0.133333333333, 0.333333333333, 0.566666666667, 0.3, 
0.766666666667, 0.166666666667, 0.233333333333, 0.4, 0.266666666667, 
0.533333333333, 1.13333333333, 0.233333333333, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.333333333333, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.566666666667, 0.466666666667, 
0.2, 0.733333333333, 0.5, 0.333333333333, 0.2, 0.333333333333, 
0.4, 0.266666666667, 0.0666666666667, 0.266666666667, 0.2, 0.433333333333, 
0.566666666667, 0.0666666666667, 0.166666666667, 0.533333333333, 
0.3, 0.433333333333, 0, 0.4, 0.466666666667, 0.0666666666667, 
0.333333333333, 0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.233333333333, 0.3, 0.0333333333333, 
0.4, 0.566666666667, 0.0333333333333, 0.0333333333333, 0.266666666667, 
0.0333333333333, 0.4, 0.466666666667, 0.166666666667, 0.633333333333, 
0.366666666667, 0.233333333333, 0.466666666667, 0.1, 0.0666666666667, 
0.4, 0.366666666667, 0.1, 0.166666666667, 0.266666666667, 0.466666666667, 
0.266666666667, 0.333333333333, 0.0333333333333, 0.1, 0.5, 0.333333333333, 
0.333333333333, 0.266666666667, 0, 0.466666666667, 0.233333333333, 
0.166666666667, 0.266666666667, 0.333333333333, 0.433333333333, 
0.1, 0.0666666666667, 0.4, 0.2, 0.133333333333, 0.533333333333, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.433333333333, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0666666666667, 0.233333333333, 
0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.266666666667, 0.233333333333, 0.6, 0.533333333333, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.0333333333333, 0.0333333333333, 0.0666666666667, 
0.166666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.166666666667, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 
0.466666666667, 0.433333333333, 0.4, 0.266666666667, 0.3, 0.4, 
0.6, 0.0333333333333, 0.0666666666667, 0.333333333333, 0.3, 0.1, 
0.333333333333, 0.333333333333, 0.2, 0.0333333333333), BM_percentage = c(82L, 
83L, 91L, 72L, 68L, 88L, 32L, 91L, 59L, 87L, 89L, 99L, 35L, 90L, 
75L, 41L, 63L, 69L, 81L, 51L, 53L, 34L, 63L, 75L, 47L, 95L, 42L, 
55L, 83L, 90L, 84L, 61L, 100L, 64L, 62L, 67L, 77L, 39L, 43L, 
75L, 69L, 73L, 72L, 80L, 90L, 39L, 74L, 78L, 51L, 37L, 92L, 57L, 
85L, 40L, 48L, 81L, 86L, 88L, 60L, 98L, 77L, 42L, 46L, 89L, 95L, 
90L, 73L, 71L, 32L, 70L, 62L, 32L, 75L, 76L, 56L, 30L, 92L, 76L, 
89L, 50L, 79L, 55L, 94L, 80L, 47L, 81L, 90L, 87L, 75L, 46L, 67L, 
70L, 86L, 72L, 85L, 40L, 97L, 83L, 57L, 60L, 52L, 90L, 52L, 86L, 
74L, 37L, 71L, 91L, 52L, 85L, 90L, 95L, 70L, 82L, 40L, 64L, 40L, 
90L, 85L, 86L, 71L, 51L, 77L, 85L, 40L, 37L, 35L, 57L, 48L, 81L, 
60L, 62L, 72L, 67L, 56L, 59L, 81L, 33L, 94L, 85L, 72L, 42L, 93L, 
40L, 86L, 71L, 79L), Risk_Cyto = structure(c(2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Good", 
"Intermediate", "N.D.", "Poor"), class = "factor"), Risk_Molecular = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Good", "Intermediate", "N.D.", "Poor"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("TCGA-AB-2856", 
"TCGA-AB-2849", "TCGA-AB-2971", "TCGA-AB-2930", "TCGA-AB-2891", 
"TCGA-AB-2872", "TCGA-AB-2851", "TCGA-AB-3011", "TCGA-AB-2949", 
"TCGA-AB-2981", "TCGA-AB-2965", "TCGA-AB-2822", "TCGA-AB-2828", 
"TCGA-AB-2959", "TCGA-AB-2973", "TCGA-AB-2987", "TCGA-AB-2986", 
"TCGA-AB-2921", "TCGA-AB-2863", "TCGA-AB-3009", "TCGA-AB-2812", 
"TCGA-AB-2940", "TCGA-AB-2996", "TCGA-AB-2983", "TCGA-AB-2859", 
"TCGA-AB-2913", "TCGA-AB-2917", "TCGA-AB-2929", "TCGA-AB-2825", 
"TCGA-AB-2897", "TCGA-AB-2900", "TCGA-AB-2846", "TCGA-AB-2862", 
"TCGA-AB-3002", "TCGA-AB-2871", "TCGA-AB-2819", "TCGA-AB-2901", 
"TCGA-AB-2920", "TCGA-AB-2966", "TCGA-AB-2814", "TCGA-AB-2942", 
"TCGA-AB-2870", "TCGA-AB-2847", "TCGA-AB-2844", "TCGA-AB-2806", 
"TCGA-AB-2911", "TCGA-AB-2980", "TCGA-AB-2861", "TCGA-AB-2916", 
"TCGA-AB-2878", "TCGA-AB-2944", "TCGA-AB-2817", "TCGA-AB-2830", 
"TCGA-AB-2892", "TCGA-AB-2858", "TCGA-AB-2815", "TCGA-AB-2877", 
"TCGA-AB-2939", "TCGA-AB-2890", "TCGA-AB-2811", "TCGA-AB-2918", 
"TCGA-AB-2898", "TCGA-AB-2908", "TCGA-AB-2866", "TCGA-AB-2842", 
"TCGA-AB-2991", "TCGA-AB-2823", "TCGA-AB-2910", "TCGA-AB-2915", 
"TCGA-AB-2977", "TCGA-AB-2912", "TCGA-AB-2943", "TCGA-AB-2881", 
"TCGA-AB-2988", "TCGA-AB-3000", "TCGA-AB-2948", "TCGA-AB-2895", 
"TCGA-AB-2931", "TCGA-AB-2956", "TCGA-AB-2936", "TCGA-AB-2934", 
"TCGA-AB-2914", "TCGA-AB-2992", "TCGA-AB-2869", "TCGA-AB-2946", 
"TCGA-AB-2894", "TCGA-AB-2963", "TCGA-AB-2928", "TCGA-AB-2924", 
"TCGA-AB-2818", "TCGA-AB-2975", "TCGA-AB-2874", "TCGA-AB-2979", 
"TCGA-AB-2826", "TCGA-AB-2990", "TCGA-AB-3001", "TCGA-AB-2885", 
"TCGA-AB-2835", "TCGA-AB-2873", "TCGA-AB-2955", "TCGA-AB-2845", 
"TCGA-AB-2836", "TCGA-AB-2925", "TCGA-AB-2884", "TCGA-AB-2820", 
"TCGA-AB-2899", "TCGA-AB-3008", "TCGA-AB-2994", "TCGA-AB-2889", 
"TCGA-AB-2853", "TCGA-AB-2896", "TCGA-AB-2893", "TCGA-AB-2867", 
"TCGA-AB-2999", "TCGA-AB-2888", "TCGA-AB-2839", "TCGA-AB-2865", 
"TCGA-AB-3007", "TCGA-AB-2932", "TCGA-AB-2976", "TCGA-AB-2834", 
"TCGA-AB-2840", "TCGA-AB-2880", "TCGA-AB-2998", "TCGA-AB-2813", 
"TCGA-AB-2882", "TCGA-AB-2995", "TCGA-AB-2950", "TCGA-AB-2810", 
"TCGA-AB-2935", "TCGA-AB-2821", "TCGA-AB-2952", "TCGA-AB-2886", 
"TCGA-AB-2805", "TCGA-AB-2876", "TCGA-AB-2808", "TCGA-AB-2937", 
"TCGA-AB-2927", "TCGA-AB-2883", "TCGA-AB-2982", "TCGA-AB-2919", 
"TCGA-AB-3012", "TCGA-AB-2841", "TCGA-AB-2875", "TCGA-AB-2984", 
"TCGA-AB-2970", "TCGA-AB-2933"))
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong here given that in my X there are groups and in y there is the dependent variable.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You could try making FAB indeed a categorical (e.g. `as.factor(FAB)`). However, upon trying to verify this, `ggwithinstats` threw two other error messages at me. Mind that the  package is still in the *maturing* state ( https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/ ).

Comment: yes i think the data need to be in different format for example this post https://yuzar-blog.netlify.app/posts/2022-01-13-pairedsampleswilcoxonsigned-ranktestinr/ to use `ggwithinstats` function the data has to be like paired if i understand from the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggwithinstats` is for plotting repeated measures in individual subjects, but the fact that you have different sized groups for `FAB` and no ID column suggests that this is *not* what you have. If the groups are different sizes, you will always get an error because you cannot have a repeated measures structure.

I suspect you are looking for `ggbetweenstats` rather than `ggwithinstats`, since all you appear to be doing is comparing different groups.

```r
ggbetweenstats( # independent samples
  data = dat,
  x = FAB,
  y = BM_percentage,
  type = "nonparametric", # for wilcoxon
  plot.type = "box", # for boxplot
  centrality.plotting = FALSE # remove median
)
```

[image]

Comment: `ggbetweenstats` actually i was trying out one goal is to compare between different groups but if i have to measure how much variability exist within each group? how to do that

Comment: @PesKchan if you want to test whether there is a significant difference in the variance of the groups you can use `library(car); leveneTest(dat$BM_percentage, dat$FAB)` which will show you that there is no significant difference between the variances (p = 0.44). If you want to see the variances in each group try `tapply(dat$BM_percentage, dat$FAB, sd)`